# How to locate and convert to integers an array of string in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, sorting, integer

I have a problem I am trying to solve. I have an array of string and integers and I want to convert only the integers(163) to actual integers in C.

I have managed to locate my desired numbers (163) array location but i am unsure how to convert them to numbers. I have tried to use strtol, atoi and strtoumax but I havent been succesful.
I have added my code below.

```
char busy[30] = {"this is; it was; 163; 234;;"};

int tag = 0;
int location = 0;
for (int i = sizeof(busy); i > 0; i--)  {
   printf("%c\n", busy[i]); 
   if (busy[i] == ';')  {
        tag = tag+1;
        printf("tag is %i \n", tag);    
   }
   if (tag == 4) {
       printf("for loop is %i\n", i);
       location = i;
       break;
   }
}
location = location+1;
int loca_saved = 0;
int loca_finish = 0;
int tag1 = 0;
while (busy[location] != ';') {
    if (busy[location] == ' ' && busy[location - 1] == ';')  {
    //printf("not printing whitespace between semicolon and characters\n");
    location++;
    }
    else    { 
        if (tag1 == 0)    {
            tag1 = tag1+1;
            loca_saved = location; //this is to tell me the array location for the first char      
        }
        if (busy[location + 1] == ';')  {
            loca_finish = location; //this is to tell me the array location for the last char
        }
    
    putchar(busy[location]); //this is to print my desired characters(163)
    location++;
    }

}
```

Comment: "I have tried to use...". Unfortunately you don't show us how you tried it or in which way your attempts failed. Your code does not contain any attempt to convert your numbers.

Answer (score 2):

`strspn` and `strcspn` can be used to parse a string.
Instead of `sscanf`, `strtol` could be used to get the number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void) {
    char busy[] = "this is; it was; 163; 234;";
    char *dlm = "0123456789";
    char *parse = busy;
    int number = 0;

    while ( *parse) {
        parse += strcspn ( parse, dlm);//count to next delimiter
        if ( 1 == sscanf ( parse, "%d", &number)) {
            printf ( "%d\n", number);
        }
        parse += strspn ( parse, dlm);//skip delimeters
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Parsing could also work off the semicolon.
Some fields will not have an integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void) {
    char busy[] = "this is; it was; 163; 234;";
    char *dlm = ";";
    char *parse = busy;
    int number = 0;

    while ( *parse) {
        if ( 1 == sscanf ( parse, "%d", &number)) {
            printf ( "%d\n", number);
        }
        else {
            printf ( "could not parse integer\n");
        }
        parse += strcspn ( parse, dlm);//count to next delimiter
        parse += strspn ( parse, dlm);//skip delimeters
        //the above line will skip all consecutive delimiters
        //to process each delimiter use the line below
        //++parse;//skip one delimiter
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi man for the second code you shared, when you skip over your second delimiter, the parse position in on a space in the array busy. how does sscanf know to not include the space and read only the integers till the semi colon? because sscanf is starting on the space position which would fail your if statement.

Comment: just to add the code does work but i am trying to understand the way it works. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the exact grammar that you would like to parse. Note, for example, that negative integers start with a `-` character, and that there has to be a maximum integer value. Since you are working quite "low level", you may want to perform the conversion to an integer while you are reading the string, e.g.:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char busy[30] = {"this is; it was; 163; 234;;"};

    for (char *p = busy; *p; ++p) // Loop over the string
        if (isdigit(*p)) // Found first digit of an unsigned integer
        {
            unsigned n = (unsigned) (*p - '0'); // Store the value of the first digit in 'n'

            // While reading the number, shift the digits to the appropriate positions
            while (isdigit(*++p))
                n = n * 10U + (unsigned) (*p - '0');

            printf("%u\n", n); // We have finished parsing the integer, print it
        }
}
```

Using `atoi` can also work, but it will require two passes over each integer: one in `atoi` itself and another one to move past the integer in the string you're parsing.

The function `strtol` allows you to pass a pointer to your pointer which is set to one place *after* the read integer, which avoids the issue. You can use this to advance the pointer. In this code example, the pointer is either advanced manually or by `strtol`:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char busy[30] = {"this is; it was; 163; 234;;"};

    for (char *p = busy; *p; )
        if (isdigit(*p))
            printf("%ld\n", strtol(p, &p, 10));
        else
            ++p;
}
```

Another alternative, without the use of `isdigit`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char busy[30] = {"this is; it was; 163; 234;;"};

    for (char *p = busy; *p; )
    {
        char *end;
        long n = strtol(p, &end, 10);
        if (p != end) // Pointer was advanced, so an integer was read
        {
            printf("%ld\n", n);
            p = end;
        }
        else // Pointer was not advanced, do so manually
            ++p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Yun,  in your first code, you have got %u? this is a mistake im assuming..?

Comment: @LePiff Hi LePiff. Thank you for the comment. It's not a mistake. It's the correct format specifier to print an unsigned int, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: Hi Yun, thanks for sharing the link. I have other question for clarification over your first code again. 

unsigned n = (unsigned) (*p - '0');
what is the purpose of (unsigned) if the variable n is already defined as unsigned?

Also why multiply by 10U rather than just 10? What is the purpose of that? 

Thanks again.

Comment: @LePiff You're welcome! Technically, it doesn't serve a purpose as the conversion will be implicit. In other words, the cast is optional. I just wanted to make it explicit that it's "`char` - `int`" cast to an `unsigned int`. The U-suffix is to denote that it's an [unsigned integer constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant). Again, just to be really explicit about the types. Both the cast and suffix can be left out, and many programmers do and that's fine too. Usually, you don't see this many conversions/casts in a program, but with `char`s and ASCII values, you do.

Comment: Hi Yun, i'm currently debugging your last code the line 
long n = strtol(p, &end, 10);
I was wondering why the value of &end equals the last character in busy array rather than the first one after the last number "163" after it has found the first digit?
Thanks again

Comment: @LePiff Debugging my code? Is there anything wrong with it? This is simply how [strtol](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) is defined, or do I not understand your question? By the way, you may want to upvote answers and/or accept an answer if these answers help you. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more info on how StackOverflow works.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a modifiable string you can use `strtok` to separate it into substrings based on the `;` delimiter. This code does that in in case a substring is a number, it gets printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
  char str[30] = {"this is; it was; 163; 234;;"};
  
  for(char* p=strtok(str, ";"); p!=NULL; p=strtok(NULL,str))
  {
    char* endptr;
    int i = strtol(p,&endptr,10);
    if(endptr != p)
    {
      printf("%d\n", i);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
163
234
```

`strtol` sets the "endptr" parameter to point at the beginning of the string in case it fails, so we can use that to determine if a substring was a number or not.